# How to get all protected items with details from Azure Site Recover

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-site-recovery

I'm working on a script for my customer and seems ASR PowerShell module is not working.

I need to connect to Azure via PowerShell and take a list of protected items. (replicated items).

Anyone tried doing that? I tried with Az and AzureRM modules.

Comment: Please use the command `Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem` . I t will return the properties of an Azure Site Recovery Replication Protected Items.

Answer (score 1):

Please know that all versions of the **AzureRM** PowerShell module are outdated, but not out of support. The **Az** PowerShell module is now the recommended PowerShell module for interacting with Azure.

Nevertheless, here are the cmdlets from both the modules:

- AzureRM module: [Get-AzureRmSiteRecoveryReplicationProtectedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.siterecovery/get-azurermsiterecoveryreplicationprotecteditem?view=azurermps-5.7.0)

```
Get-AzureRmSiteRecoveryReplicationProtectedItem
   -ProtectionContainer <ASRProtectionContainer>
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

- Az Module: [Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.recoveryservices/get-azrecoveryservicesasrreplicationprotecteditem?view=azps-4.8.0)

```
Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem
   -ProtectionContainer <ASRProtectionContainer>
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Answer (score 1):

First authorize to Azure then do:

```
$VaultName = 'name-of-recovery-service-vault'
$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $VaultName
Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext -Vault $vault
$fabric = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrFabric
$container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer -Fabric $fabric
Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem -ProtectionContainer $container
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. I had to do multiple loops to get all the info

Script supports multiple subscriptions and recovery service vaults.
I also query for a TAG on the VM.
Output to a CSV file.

```
# Connect to Azure
Connect-AzAccount

# Get all Azure subscriptions
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Create an array to store the results
$results = @()

# Loop through each subscription
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    
    # Select the current subscription
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

# Get all vaults
$vaults = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault

# Loop through each vault
foreach ($vault in $vaults) {
    
    # Select the current vault
    Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext -Vault $vault

# Get all fabrics
$fabrics = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrFabric

# Loop through each fabric
foreach ($fabric in $fabrics) {
    
    # Get the asr container
    $container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer -Fabric $fabric
    
    # Get protected Items
    $items= Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem -ProtectionContainer $container

# Loop through each item
foreach ($item in $items) {

        # Check if replication is enabled for the virtual machine
        if ($item -ne $null) {
        
        # Get VM object to be able to populate with VM parameters
        $vm = get-azvm | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $item.FriendlyName}
        
            $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
                "Subscription" = $subscription.Name
                "RecoveryVault" = $vault.Name
                "Fabric" = $fabric.Name
                "VirtualMachineName" = $item.FriendlyName
                "AppName" = $vm.Tags.AppName
                "ActiveLocation" = $item.ActiveLocation
                "ProtectionState" = $item.ProtectionState
                "ReplicationHealth" = $item.ReplicationHealth

            } 
            $results += $result
            } #end if

} #end VM loop

} #end fabric loop

} #end vault loop

} #end sub loop

# Output the results to a CSV file
$results | Export-Csv -Path "VirtualMachineReplicationStatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```