# Azure Site Recovery - Powershell - How to get a list of all the VMs in a Recovery Plan

Tags: azure, powershell

I can get an Azure Site Recovery plan with powershell :

```
$RecoveryPlan = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrRecoveryPlan | where {$_.name -eq "MyRecPlan"}
```

But how do I get a list of all the VMs in this plan with powershell?

Answer (score 0):

> how do I get a list of all the VMs in this plan with powershell?

Here is the `PowerShell` script that retrieves the list of `VMs` in a **recovery plan** from a recovery vault.

```
    $recoveryPlan = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrRecoveryPlan -Name 'Demo-RSV-Plan'
    $fabrics = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrFabric
    $containers = @()
    $protectedItems = @()
    
    foreach ($fabric in $fabrics) {
        $container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer -Fabric $fabric
        $containers += $container
    
        $protectItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem -ProtectionContainer $container
        $protectedItems += $protectItem
    }
    
    
    $results = @()
    
    foreach ($item in $protectedItems) {
        $policyId = $item.PolicyID
    
        $parts = $policyId -split '/'
        $SubscriptionID = $parts[2]
        $ResourceGroupName = $parts[4]
        $VaultName = $parts[8]
    
        $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Subscription ID" = $SubscriptionID
            "RecoveryVault" =  $VaultName
            "Resource Group Name" = $ResourceGroupName
            "VirtualMachineName" = $item.RecoveryAzureVMName
            "Recovery Plan Name" = $recoveryPlan.Name
        } 
        $results += $result
    }
    
    $results | Format-Table -Property "Subscription ID", "RecoveryVault", "Resource Group Name", "VirtualMachineName"
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:** [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62327894/how-to-get-all-protected-items-with-details-from-azure-site-recover)

Comment: Thanks .. this looks like it is getting a list of all protected items and them putting them into a results array. But it is possible to have a protected item that is not in a recovery plan.

Comment: If you want to filter out protected items that are not included in any recovery plan, you can use not null condition, if ($item.RecoveryPlanId -ne $null).

Comment: That is not what I am saying. This results array gives all replicated items, whether they are in a Recovery Plan or not!

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the portal that shows what you need.